# Vue.js implementing Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am doing a tutorial on Vue.js and encounter this problem. The issue occurs when I tried to import the router in main.js. When I run the server, I got this error.

**Error on the console:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
    at eval (main.js?56d7:6)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1475)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1500)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
    at app.js:925
    at app.js:928
```

**`Main.js`**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import routes from './router.js'

Vue.use(Router);


new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    router: routes,
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

`vue-router` doesn't expose a Vue plugin, but a constructor that returns the configured plugin.

You should check the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript)(section #Getting started).

The installation of `vue-router` consists of three steps:

- Declare your route and assign each view component to your routes
- Export the built router
- Use the router in your app.

```js
// 1. Define route components.
// These can be imported from other files
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

// 2. Define some routes
// Each route should map to a component. The "component" can
// either be an actual component constructor created via
// `Vue.extend()`, or just a component options object.
// We'll talk about nested routes later.
const routes = [
  { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

// 3. Create the router instance and pass the `routes` option
// You can pass in additional options here, but let's
// keep it simple for now.
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

// 4. Create and mount the root instance.
// Make sure to inject the router with the router option to make the
// whole app router-aware.
const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')

// Now the app has started!
```